# Is it possible to make a link for a specific Twitter post?

Tags: twitter, links

I want to share a specific Twitter post to my friend. For that I need to make a link for that post. How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the latest incarnation of Twitter the link is now called "Expand" and has moved under the Tweet:

[image: How to get the direct link to the Tweet]

If you actually click on the "Expand" link you get three more places to pick up the link - the time, the "Collapse" link and the "Details" link:

[image: Even more places]

<sub>*See the revision history for previous locations of this link*</sub>

Comment: Pushing it further you can use [BlackPie](http://media.twitter.com/blackbird-pie/) for embedding tweets to your blog http://media.twitter.com/291/ash-cloud

Answer (score 11):

Click on the timestamp.

> **7 hours ago** via Twitter for iPhone

Answer (score 4):

With the new Twitter layout, the currently accepted answer no longer works.

Now you need to first `Open` a tweet in your feed by clicking on the `Open` link in the upper right, or by clicking in any of the whitespace of the tweet which is any non-link areas.

The permalink for the post is now the `Details` link which should be roughly in the lower middle of the tweet just to the right of the *date* and the *via* segments.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use new twitter API to embed tweets on a web page the tweet thus embedded looks better than the one blackbird pie did the tweet embedded  Is small and with nifty links {reply, favorite, and retweet} embedded code looks like this

[image]

You can get the tweet embed code in the details link and via getting to the single tweet page!

[image]

Refer to [this guide](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets)