# How do you permalink to tweets?

Tags: twitter, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make a link for a specific Twitter post?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/is-it-possible-to-make-a-link-for-a-specific-twitter-post)

Maybe this is obvious, but for a given tweet how do I find or determine the permalink URL (or direct URL to just that tweet)? This is without using a 3rd party client, just using the "new" twitter.com.